# Getting Generic Access Token, Invalid callback

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-oauth, facebook-access-token

I am trying to get a generic facebook access token. All the tutorials I read recommend using the call below.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&
client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&
grant_type=client_credentials
```

This generates an access token with I paste it into the browser. However when I try this with my App Id and App Secret using the code below with the javascript SDK.

```
FB.api('/oauth/access_token?
client_id=MY_APP_ID&client_secret=MY_APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials',  
$.proxy( function(response) {
},this));
```

I get the following response.

```
{"error":{"type":"http","message":"unknown error"}}
```

Any ideas as to what's going wrong?

Comment: I am guessing you tried this through Graph Explorer, if yes then try to navigate to the end point directly. There seems to be some problem with explorer and this end point

Comment: Hi Anvesh, thanks for your comment. I tried making the call via pasting the call into a browser and a javascript SDK rest call. The browser method worked but the javascript SDK generated a different error (see edit above).

Comment: what is `$.proxy` this for in callback function?

Comment: That's a jQuery Mobile function that changes the closure of the function so you can reference outside variables. I've used it on other instances of FB.api with out a problem and it doesn't make a difference if I remove it.

Comment: It is a stupid idea to use the app access token client-side, because every user could steal it. The fact that you are putting your app secret into client-side code here should already alert you that you are doing something wrong here - please think for a moment why it is called app _secret_ ...

Comment: Well I tried the same in the Javascript SDK and it comes out that the response is returned to us but the SDK is not able to interpret the same giving out errors on console `Uncaught ReferenceError: A************w is not defined `. You would have to launch a bug report at [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs) cause this we won't be able to solve.

Comment: CBroe, isn't it secure if I set the javaScript file containing the app secret, so it it isn't visible to the public?